# Mobx cannot set property '@observable' of undefined when filled with JSON-Object

Tags: json, reactjs, rest, axios, mobx

Im having an issue with saving JSON-Image-Files to mobx observables as follows.

This is my Axios call where the Problem occurs:

```
 @observable images = [];
 @action getAllImages() {
    const payload = {
      "token": getTokenFromLocalStorage
    }

            axios.get(API_BASE_URL + '/user/images', payload)
              .then(function(response) {
                if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                  console.log("RESPONSE IMAGE:" + JSON.stringify(response.data.files, null, 2));
     >>               this.images = response.data.files;
                  console.log("IMAGESTORE IN AXIOS " + this.images[0]);
                } else {
                  alert("error getting images");
                }
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("DOWNLOAD: " + error);
              });
  }
```

This Part `this.images = response.data.files;` throws an exception: `Cannot set property 'images' of undefined`

Output of above line:

```
RESPONSE IMAGE:[
  "img_1612801479594.jpg",
  "img_1612802187709.jpg",
  "img_1612802491363.jpg",
  "img_1612803744426.jpg"
]
```

Why cant I assign the Array with Image-Objects to this observable? This seems really confusing to me.

This is my Node-JS Backend that sends the JSON-Response:

```
router.get("/images", function(req, res) {
  // Sends all available images
  let sendFiles = [];
  let files = fs.readdirSync(imagePath);
  files.forEach(file => {
    if (file.includes("jpg") ||
        file.includes("jpeg") ||
        file.includes("JPEG") ||
        file.includes("png") ||
        file.includes("PNG")) {
      sendFiles.push(file)
    }
  });
  res.send({files: sendFiles});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when your write function handlers within then or catch, they will have there own context. For the below code,

```
this.images = response.data.files;
```

'this', refers to the context of 'then' function. It will not have 'images' declared within that function.

If your using es6, below code would work as long as you have declared the 'images'

```
axios.get(API_BASE_URL + '/user/images', payload)
      >>        .then((response) => {
                if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                  console.log("RESPONSE IMAGE:" + JSON.stringify(response.data.files, null, 2));
     >>               this.images = response.data.files;
                  console.log("IMAGESTORE IN AXIOS " + this.images[0]);
                } else {
                  alert("error getting images");
                }
              })
    >>          .catch((error) => {
                console.log("DOWNLOAD: " + error);
              });
```